# How to render image using path from json in hugo

Tags: hugo

The project structures look like this.

```
/
|__ assets
|   |__ imgs
|       |__ pic-nodejs.jpg
|       |__ pic-denojs.jpg
|
|__ data
|   |__ products.json
|
|__ layouts
    |__ _default
    |   |__ baseof.html
    |
    |__ partials
    |   |__ card.html
    |
    |__ index.html
```

The project goal is basically to display a list of products with a Bootstrap-ish card style in a grid layout.
Below are the snippets from the above files.

`/data/products.json`

```json
[
  {
    "Uid": "110",
    "Name": "Nodejs",
    "Imgsrc": "imgs/pic-nodejs.jpg"
  },
  {
    "Uid": "120",
    "Name": "Denojs",
    "Imgsrc": "imgs/pic-denojs.jpg"
  }
]
```

`index.html`

```html
{{ define "main" }}
  <section>
    {{ partial "card.html" . }}
  </section>
{{ end }}
```

`partials/card.html`

```html
{{ $data := getJSON "/data/products.json" }}
{{ range $data }}
  <header>
    <h2>{{ .Name }}</h2>
  </header>
  <img src={{ .Imgsrc }} alt={{ .Name }} />
{{ end }}
```

The expected output for `card.html`.

```html
<section>
  <header>
    <h2>Nodejs</h2>
  </header>
  <img src="imgs/pic-nodejs.jpg" alt="Nodejs" />
</section>
```

I've got this instead.

```html
<section>
  <header>
    <h2>Nodejs</h2>
  </header>
  <img src="" alt="Nodejs" />
</section>
```

**No image being loaded.**
Any idea how to do this?

I'm currently using HUGO v0.88.1 Extended.

Comment: That is how to do it... I do not see an error in your code. Is the `Imgsrc` string really empty?

Answer (score 0):

Move the folder **imgs** inside **static** folder

check [this branch](https://github.com/cromozooom/playground-hugo/tree/q69810554) of my repo